# which of the following is an equivalence relation of the set S

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

which of the following is an equivalence relation of the set S

[image]

I have solved all except d and need your help please

Comment: Do you have any ideas?  Were you able to check any of the properties of an equivalence relation?  Is the relation reflexive?  Is the relation transitive?

Comment: So, why don't you show us what you've tried to solve d?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $n = 10$.  Then, for example, $7 \sim 2$ because $7-2 = 5$ divides $10$.  Can you find any $c$ such that $c \sim 7$ but $c \not\sim 2$?

Comment: so equivalence relation  or not ???

Comment: Well, put some thought into it.  If you found such a $c$, would that mean it was an equivalence relation, or not?  It's your homework, not mine...